# Why does acidity increase going from sulfide to sulfoxide to sulfone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, organosulfur-compounds

It is fairly well-known that the acidity of a proton alpha to a sulfide/sulfoxide/sulfone increases in that order. Some p*K*<sub>a</sub> values (in DMSO), courtesy of the [Evans p*K*<sub>a</sub> table](http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf):

[image: acidities of sulfide vs sulfoxide vs sulfone]

Traditionally this has been explained by *resonance*, or delocalisation of the carbon-based negative charge onto oxygen (left, below). But this necessarily invokes hypervalency and a S=O double bond. The major resonance form in a sulfoxide should be the charge-separated, octet-compliant form (right, below).

[image: resonance forms of sulfoxide and sulfoxide anion]

What is the proper explanation for the acidity trend above, then?

Comment: So if we were just considering inductive effects, how much would we expect the $\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}}$ value to drop for every extra oxygen in a $\beta$-position?

Comment: @Zhe I actually suspect it is perhaps more to do with the positive charge on sulfur, rather than the oxygen (don't think the oxygen really does much, cf. acidity of typical alkane vs typical ether) But I don't have a good source, it's just a hunch.

Comment: Isn't the positive charge on sulfur just caused by the electronegative oxygens?

Comment: @Zhe the positive formal charge, I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oxidation state of sulphur and its therefore increased inductive effect should be enough to explain this effect.

Besides the number of oxygens, the principle difference between the three structures is the oxidation state of sulphur that rises from $\mathrm{-II}$ to $\pm0$ to $\mathrm{+II}$. The higher an element’s oxidation state, the stronger it draws electrons towards itself since a higher oxidation state typically correlates with less electron density.

Unfortunately, we cannot draw good comparisons. Phosphorus would suggest itself, but neither the Evans table nor the Bordwell data have enough data points for scrutinisation. Furthermore, phosphorus is less electronegative than carbon, meaning the bonds would be polarised towards carbon.

Chlorine might be an option being on the other side of sulphur in the periodic table, but to the best of my knowledge no ‘chlorone’ or ‘chloroxide’ organic compounds are known let alone their acidities.

Nitrogen in its higher oxidation state (a nitro group) has a double bond which can resonate with the negative charge so it is not a good comparison. And the elements in the fourth period and below are again too electropositive in general. If anything, we may be able to draw conclusions based on the β-acidity of an ether, the α-acidity of an acetal/ketal or the α-acidity of an — if these are even stable enough to be deprotonated.

Comment: Well, there's for example [Perchlorylbenzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perchlorylbenzene), so some analogies might be drawn.

Comment: @Mithoron Didn’t know it existed!

Comment: Found this in [*J. Phys. Chem. A* **2005,** *109,* 4966](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp058010f): *"The acidity trend apparently stems from other factors* [than resonance], *such as the electrical stabilization of the anionic carbon center adjacent to polarized sulfenyl (RS), sulfinyl (RSO), and sulfonyl (RSO2) groups."* I agree that sulfur electronegativity is probably the best explanation. For analogies, amine vs. *N*-oxide might work, but I wonder if the data exists.

Comment: @orthocresol Oooh, I wonder whether someone wants to add a literature-suppored answer to this Q.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Clayden (Reference 1), $\ce{ ^13 C}$ NMR can give insights into the acidity of the $\alpha$-carbon in sulfide/sulfoxide/sulfone compounds. As @orthocresol informs, the resonance is not essential. Then, as explained by @Jan, the inductive effects are important in the sequence n oxygen(s)  O (n=0, 1,2) to sulfur S to $\alpha$-carbon C and vice versa, considering mainly the electronegativity interaction of these three elements series (in der Aufeinanderfolge, in der Rehie). In this context, $\ce{ ^17 O}$ and $\ce{ ^33 S}$ NMR (Reference 2) would be useful to clarify these inductive effects. Also, the importance of the inductive effects of the resonance and inductive effects can be elucidated through the Hammet constants $\rho$, as shown in exercise 93 of Chapter 17 of Reference 3.

References.

Reference 1. J. Clayden, N. Greeves, S. Warren and P. Wothers. “Organic Chemistry”, Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2012, p.501 (figure of conjugated and not conjugated 13C NMR: 132, 143 ppm, respectively).

Reference 2. S. A. Evans Jr., Oxygen-17 and Sulfur-33 Nuclear Magnetic Resonance Spectroscopy of Organosulfur Compounds, NATO Series 124, Magnetic Resonance, 757-766,  1984.

Reference 3. P. Y. Bruice, “Organic Chemistry”, 6th Edition, Prentice Hall, p. 187, p. 770.